# How run windows appliacation package project on HoloLens emulator?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, hololens

I exported a WPF project to UWP and I want to run the built application package project on a HoloLens emulator, but it doesn't exist in running parameters. [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwEoQ.png) [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZeuZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging a WPF desktop application as an APPX or MSIX does *not* make it universal in the sense that it will run on anything else than desktop devices.

A desktop app is still an x86 or x64 bit application and it won't run on HoloLens.

Comment: Thanks. And is there an opportunity to wrap the WPF project for HoloLens, does it have to be rewritten to UWP?

Comment: @ВладМакух: You need to rewrite the app as a UWP.